# Returning DB Query Result as List in a WebService

Tags: c#, linq, list, web-services

im trying to return a list in a web service method with the results of some db queries.

**My Query is:**

```
var Address = (from table in Model.Table where *-some conditions and join clause-* select Address).Firstordefault();

var Phone =(from table in Model.Table where *-some conditions and join clause-* select Phone).FirstOrDefault();
```

**Web Service Method:**

```
[WebMethod]
public List< x> ShowDetails(*input parameters*) 
{

  List< x> list = new List<x>();

  list.Add(Address);

  list.Add(Phone);

  return list;

}
```

My question is how can i define the `List< x>` elements with my query results?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see the reason to use a list here. Simple solution is create a custom class to save both result:

```
public class X
{
  public Address Address{get;set;}
  public Phone Pnone {get;set;}
}
```

And then you can do the following:

```
[WebMethod]
public X ShowDetails(*input parameters*) 
{

  var address = Model.Addresses.FirstorDefault(some conditions);

 var phone = Model.Phones.FirstorDefault(some conditions);

  return new X{Address=address, Phone=phone}; 
}
```

Now I see that you mention you are also joining tables probably to apply some conditions. I suggest you instead of that you use navigation properties,eg:

```
var address = Model.Addresses.FirstorDefault(a=>a.State.StateId==9);
```

That query is going to do the join for you once it's translated to sql.

Comment: @ickr90,You're welcome. I saw now that you are a new member of SO, welcome ;). If you think my answer help you to solve your issue, please consider mark your question as answered by clicking the check-mark.There is no obligation to do this.